# getChildAt always returns null

Tags: android, android-gridview

I've set up a gridview in a fragment  in onCreateView to display days of the week as follows:

```
weekGridView = (GridView)view.findViewById(R.id.weekGrid);

// set up days of week grid
dayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ShowEventsNavFragment.this.getActivity(), R.layout.event_gridview_header_cell, R.id.cellTextView, days);
headerGrid.setAdapter(dayAdapter);
```

The cell layout I'm using designated R.layout.event_gridview_header_cell is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cellTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In the fragment's onStart method, I am trying to highlight a particular cell using:

```
int highlightDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)weekGridView.getChildAt(highlightDay);
rl.setBackgroundColor(0x448FCC85);
```

Unfortunately, the getChildAt method always returns null.  If I query the gridview, I find that it is visible, but that it has no children.  The gridview is clearly visible on the screen and populated with the correct values.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You should put that code in your adapter.

Comment: are you invoking getChildAt() in onCreate() method? try using it any other method like onResume()

Comment: It is worth noting that DAY_OF_WEEK has values 1-7, not 0-6.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  Which code do you recommend putting in the adapter?  The getChildAt is invoked in the onStart method of the Fragment so the view is visible.

Comment: I did verify that the onItemClickListener for the gridview returns the correct view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to override the `getView(...)` method of your adapter. Try to do this:

```
dayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.event_gridview_header_cell, R.id.cellTextView, days) {
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, android.view.ViewGroup parent) {
        View result = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        int highlightDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)
        // if I am right with indexing ...
        if(position == highlightDay - 1) {
            result.setBackgroundColor(0x448FCC85);
        } else {
            // set another background ... this is the default background, you have to provide this because the views are reused
        }
        return result;
    };
}
```

Comment: it should be (highlightday - 1) since it isn't 0 based

Comment: @KennyC: thanks, that's why I put the comment, I was waiting for someone else's comment on that as I wasn't sure if it's zero-index based :) +1

Comment: Much appreciated.  Does the getChildAt on my gridview trigger this behavior?

Comment: remove the calls to `getChildAt()` ... you don't need that. `getView(...)` will be called when the gridview is first setup and when the user is scrolling it.